# Excel Formula - Sum formula for every row in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, lookup

Sorry if this is address anywhere else. I can't think of a way to summarise it which finds me the answer. (Probably because the answer is no)

Basically I want to sum all the terms in a formula. Each term looks up data from a row in a table. I want to be able to extend the table without having to add extra terms to the formula. This is my current working formula. The lookup table is B2:C7.

> `=(HLOOKUP($B$2,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$2) + (HLOOKUP($B$3,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$3) + (HLOOKUP($B$4,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$4) + (HLOOKUP($B$5,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$5) +(HLOOKUP($B$6,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$6) + (HLOOKUP($B$7,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$7)`

The formula for each term is obviously (`HLOOKUP($B$2,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*$C$2)` where the changing values are the HLOOKUP value and the multiplication cell on the end.

My question is, is there a way to do something like this

```
=SUM((HLOOKUP(B2:B7,GramData, VLOOKUP($F4, Finder, 2, FALSE), FALSE)*C2:C7))
```

(This doesn't work) Without having to use VBA.

Comment: Should there be a * in front of all those multiplication cells? Also can you say what ranges are in GramData and Finder? And maybe a sample of the data.

Comment: Stackoverflow got rid of the * for some reason. Both those requests are independent of the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally you will find that people are just trying to be helpful (someone has already edited your question to fix that problem with the asterisks) and if they request more info it's just so they can understand your question better.

Comment: You can probably use `SUMPRODUCT` to do what you need.

Comment: Tom, I understand you're trying to be helpful. I'm not new to stack overflow, it was jsut easier to sign in using my facebook then my linux account. I try to keep my questions as isolated as possible so as to not scare away people who do know the answer. If there is an answer then it's a simple matter of syntax

Comment: Well I'd have to resort to a helper column to do it (because although the syntax is OK it doesn't iterate over the ranges B2:B7 and C2:C7 as you would want it to even if you enter it as an array formula)

Comment: Fair enough, my gut feeling was just that there would be a excel formula to do something like this. Problem is there are 6 rows to the table I want to easily extend currently then they produce 26 values. Those 26 values are what I want to add on top of each other. I'll just add the terms in manually then drag the formla, probably easiest.